# How can I upgrade my validation in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, validation, form

How to improve my validation in JavaScript?

Namely I am wondering whether some parts of code can be shortened, improved, or removed althogether.

I don't want to change the ES5 syntax because so far I am not familiar with Es6 syntax.

I also want to avoid using jQuery.

This is my validation code: https://codepen.io/RobotHabanera/pen/NWbKJLe

```
var form = document.querySelector('form');
    var errormessage = document.querySelector('.error-message');
    form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // musimy zalożyć czy formularz jest poprawnie wypełniony czy nie
        var errors = [];
        errormessage.innerHTML = '';
        var clearAllParagraphsAtTheStart = document.querySelectorAll('.form-group p');
        clearAllParagraphsAtTheStart.forEach(function(item) {
            item.innerHTML = '';
        });
        // sprawdzić czy walidacja bedzie działać
        for (var i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i++) {
            var field = form.elements[i];
            switch (field.name) {
                case 'email':
                    // najpierw negujemy funkcje hasMonkeyInFiled i jesli negacja przebiegnie prawidłowo to wykona się prawa strona komunikatu && bo
                    // jesli negacja nie przebiegnie prawidłowo to linijka z prawej sterony sie nie wykona.
                    !hasMonkeyInFiled(field) && errors.push({
                        email: 'Email musi posiadać znak @'
                    });
                    break;
                case 'name':
                    !hasMoreThanTwoChars(field) && errors.push({
                        name: 'Twoje imię jest za krótkie'
                    });
                    break;
                case 'surname':
                    !hasMoreThanSixChars(field) && errors.push({
                        surname: 'Twoje nazwisko jest za krótkie'
                    });
                    break;
                case 'pass1':
                    !hasCorrectPassword(field, form.elements[i + 1]) && errors.push({
                        pass1: 'Hasła nie są takie same lub puste'
                    });
                    break;
                case 'pass2':
                    !hasCorrectPassword(field, form.elements[i - 1]) && errors.push({
                        pass2: 'Hasła nie są takie same lub puste'
                    });
                    break;
                case 'agree':
                    !isChecked(field) && errors.push({
                        agree: 'Musisz zaakceptować warunki'
                    });
                    break;
            }
        }
        if (errors.length) {
            e.preventDefault();
            errors = errors.filter(function(v, i, a) {
                return a.indexOf(v) === i;
            });
            errors.forEach(function(item, index) {
                // wklej wartość klucza z tablicy errors gdzie nazwa klucza jest równa wartości danego data-validation bierzącego inputa z pętli
                var currentKey = Object.keys(errors[index]);
                var currentValue = Object.values(errors[index]);
                var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.form-group input');
                inputs.forEach(function(item, index) {
                    if (item.dataset.validation == currentKey) {
                        var elementP = document.createElement('p');
                        elementP.innerHTML = currentValue;
                        item.after(elementP);
                    }
                });
                /* errormessage.append(elementP);  */
            });
        }
    });

    function hasCorrectPassword(field1, field2) {
        if (hasMatch(field1, field2) && hasNumberChar(field1) && hasNumberChar(field1)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    // paramertr 'field' to jest input element
    function hasMonkeyInFiled(field) {
        return field.value.indexOf('@') > -1;
    }
    // input ma wiecej niz 6 znakow
    function hasMoreThanSixChars(field) {
        return field.value.length > 6;
    }
    // input ma wiecej niz 2 znaki
    function hasMoreThanTwoChars(field) {
        return field.value.length > 2;
    }
    // checkbox musi byc zaznaczony
    function isChecked(field) {
        return field.checked;
    }
    // pierwsze i drugie hasło są identyczne ale nie puste
    function hasMatch(field1, field2) {
        // jak sprawdzic czy nie sa puste
        if (field1.value.length && field1.value.length) {
            return field1.value == field2.value;
        }
        return false;
    }
    // Warunek dla chętnych. Dodatkowe. Hasło ma mieć co najmniej 6 znaków (w tym co najmniej jedną liczbę i jedną literę)
    function hasNumberChar(field) {
        var numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
        var hasNumber = false;
        numbers.forEach(function(number) {
            if (field.value.indexOf(number) > -1) {
                hasNumber = true;
            }
        });
        return hasNumber;
    }

    function hasLetterChar(field) {
        var chars = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];
        var hasChar = false;
        chars.forEach(function(char) {
            if (field.value.toLowerCase().indexOf(chars) > -1) {
                hasChar = true;
            }
        });
        return hasChar;
    }
    // input ma wiecej niz 5 znakow
    function hasMoreThanFiveChars(field) {
        return field.value.length > 5;
    }

    function isPangram(string) {
        string.replace(/ /g, '');
        for (var i = 0; i < string.trim().length; i++) {
            var array = [];
            var chars = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];
            chars.forEach(function(char) {
                if (char == string.substr(string[i], 1)) {} else {
                    array.push(string[i])
                }
            });
        }
        if (array.length) {}
        // bierze pierwszą litere z tablicy i jedzie tą literą po wszystkich znakach tekstu 
        string.replace(/ /g, '');
        chars.forEach(function(char) {
            for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
                var chars = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];
                if (char == string[i]) {
                    console.log('jest');
                } else {
                    console.log('nie ma');
                }
            }
        });
    };

    function isPangram(string) {
        string.replace(/ /g, '');
        var array = [];
        var chars = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];
        chars.forEach(function(char) {
            for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
                // każda litera alfabetu ma przejechać po tekście 
                if (char == string[i]) {
                    array.push(string[i]);
                } else {}
            }
            if (array.length > 0) {
                console.log('jest')
            }
        });
    };
```

Comment: Please explain in the question a little more about what the code is validating. That helps us review the code. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

### The validation functionality

Overall the validation function looks reasonable. You have a `preventDefault` at the beginning that blocks the form from ever being sent, but other than that it looks logically structured. You first clear all your previous errors, then look if there are any new errors, and finally show the new errors. You can consider factoring out those three parts, but I don't think it is needed in this particular case.

There are however some issues with the functions you call though, and some false assumptions you make in and around them.

#### `hasMoreThanTwoChars`

Whenever you find yourself writing numbers inside function names, it usually means you are doing something wrong. There is either a better description (e.g. `fibonacci` instead of `addLastTwoItemsOfSequence`) or in your case, you can and should factor out the number to a parameter.

In your case you can write a function `hasMinimumNumberOfCharacters(field, numberOfCharacters)` that handles all three variants.

#### `name` and `surname`

While the following article is more than ten years old, it is still very much applicable: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/). For example, I can't fill in your form without padding my name with spaces or something weird like that.

#### `hasCorrectPassword`

You call your `hasCorrectPassword` function with `form.elements[i - 1]` and `form.elements[i + 1]`. You are almost guaranteed that this will break at some point due to re-ordering or adding of fields. Make it more robust by referencing the fields themselves by name, for example through `document.querySelector('#pass2')`.

Furthermore, the function itself is odd, because it performs two functions. You should probably split it up in two well-defined functions. One is `isEqualToField(field1, field2)` and one is `containsNumber(field)`. If your password requirements become more complex you could instead consider `isValidPassword(field)` and `isEqualToField(field1, field2)`.

You also seem to be checking twice if the same field has a number character.

And finally if you have an if-else statement that either returns true or false, you can just return the condition of the if-else statement itself.

```javascript
function hasCorrectPassword(field1, field2) {
  return hasMatch(field1, field2) && hasNumberChar(field1);
}
```

#### `hasMatch`

Always check equality using `===`. Always be mindful of the types of variables and never rely on automatic type conversion for your code to work.

#### `hasNumberChar`

This function can be improved in many ways. `numbers` is an array of `Number`, and you rely on `String.indexOf` to cast the items to a string. You could make it an array of String to be more mindful when you are using String and when you are using Number. Additionally, it is not very nice to have to define a whitelist of characters, but I suppose we will not use any other digits than the 10 we have defined here.

Instead of `Array.forEach` which requires you to loop through all items, you could use several other methods that allow you to return early.

`Array.some(func)` and `Array.every(func)` return a boolean if respectively one or all of the items in the array meet a condition, and return early. You would rewrite it as

```javascript
digits.some(function (digit) {
  // This string contains the digit we are looking for
  return field.value.indexOf(digit) !== -1;
});
```

You can rewrite `forEach` loops with a `for(const x of myArray)` as well, with the added benefit that you can return from this loop or break out of the loop.

```javascript
for (const digit of digits) {
  if (field.value.indexOf(digit) > -1) {
    return true;
  }
}

return false;
```

Both of these approaches have as additional benefit that you are not keeping track of `hasNumbers`, but return instantly when you know the answer.

#### `hasLetterChar`

This function has the same problems as the previous one, except that we have one more problem. Your language contains many characters that do not match your whitelist and relying on that whitelist will cause problems at least for a subset of your users. Even in languages where characters outside this whitelist are uncommon or non-existent should not rely on such a whitelist. For the why, I refer again back to the article a few sections above here.

If you decide to keep it at all, consider if a check if it contains anything but whitespace would suffice (`value.match(/\S/)`). Otherwise look into something like [this question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/150033/2209007), but realise that you will likely miss entire scripts and people will be annoyed they can't enter their name because of overly restrictive validators.

#### `isPangram`

The function `isPangram` is defined twice, and twice it does not return a boolean. Since it serves no purpose, it should be removed.

Both functions contain weird things like empty if or else statements, issues like not using strict equality `===` as mentioned before and the odd whitelist.

### Use `let` instead of `var`

Even if you use nothing else than this from modern javascript, use `let` when declaring variables instead of `var`. Variables declared with `var` can be read and written to outside the context you would expect them to be used. An example of that is [variables defined with var inside loops being accessible outside that loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18465211/2209007). Using `let` will magically fix that by only being available to read and write once you define it, and properly being discarded at the end of the block it is defined in. Some heavy reading about scoping can be found in [What is the scope of variables in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500431/2209007).

```js
function testWithLet() {
  // console.log(x); // Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined
  // x += 5; // Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    const x = 1;
  }
  // console.log(i); // Uncaught ReferenceError: i is not defined
}

function testWithVar() {
  console.log(x); // undefined
  x += 5; // What did this just do?
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var x = 1;
  }
  console.log(i); // 5
}

testWithLet();
testWithVar();
```

### Some additional notes based on the codepen

Keep in mind that the browser already has built-in functionality both for validating and making it easier to fill in form fields. In particular, use `type` to define things like `email`, `tel` or `number`. You can (but don't have to) define patterns the input should be adhering to. ([docs on mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input))

Use the `inputmode` attribute to give a hint to the browser which on-screen keyboard they should use. This is in particular nice for the fast majority of people who use a mobile device to use the form. Valid values include `text`, `tel`, `email` and `url`. ([docs on mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/inputmode))

Labels should be associated with their form fields. Either use `<label>label text: <input /></label>` or the `for=".."` attribute on the label to link it to an input. You do this so people with screenreaders have any idea what they are looking at, and to allow people to select the field by clicking the label.

Comment: Wow, nice work man, I will read it thoroughly soom so that I can share my thoughts on what you wrote, thank you

Comment: You state in regard to `var`  *" ...do not follow scoping very well"* which is incorrect, and *"...to the top..."* should be "to the top of the function or global scope" Your statements on the use of `let` are plainly just doctrine. Provided accurate information, if its too much to write, provide links. I will not down vote as the rest of the answer is good (should have been accepted)

Comment: I disagree with your statement, but I have changed the wording a little bit, added links and added an example. I suppose you could see that `var` follows function/global scoping very well if you take into account hoisting to the top of that function, but to people not intimately familiar with the quirks of javascript variables declared with `var` just do "weird shit". And there is [no real reason to use it anymore](https://caniuse.com/?search=let).

Comment: @Sumurai8 Plenty of reasons to use  `var`. `let` in global scope is dangerous and counter intuitive. `let` adds the name to the global closure but not to the global scope. Meaning  `<script>typeof a; let a</script>` will throw an error but `<script>typeof a</script><script>let a</script>` will not. That `<script>let a=0;setTimeout(()=>console.log(a))</script><script>a=1</script>` will counter intuitively log `1` rather than `0` even in strict mode. Poor use of `let` (or `const`) inside loops can result in huge memory use increases if the variable is closed over, which `var` is immune to.

Comment: Noted. `setTimeout` is unrelated to `let` afaik and while I can't find a larger article about it anymore, [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51728939/2209007) goes into more detail what happens. The other ones I have not encountered myself, but I will look into it.

Comment: @Sumurai8  I think you may have missed the point. The timeout is not the issue. The problem is that scripts are not blocks, yet it is almost ubiquitous to treat them as such. When do you see scripts opened and closed with `{`, `}` eg `<script>{ let a }</script>`. The expectation in the example is `<script>{ let a=0;setTimeout(()=>console.log(a)) }</script><script>a=1</script>` console will log `0`